# Алгоритм поиска простых чисел на python

Tags: python, простые-числа

идея в том, чтобы создать список из простых чисел и последовательно проверять делится ли число на каждый элемент списка и если нет, то добавлять его в этот список. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает и как это исправить.

```
simples = [2,3,5,7,11]
def issimple(n):
    i=12
    while i <= n:
        for x in simples:
            if i % x != 0 and x == len(simples):
                simples.append(i)
            else:
                pass
        i = i + 1
    return simples

tocount = int(input('Введите число: '))
print(issimple(tocount))
```

Comment: Какой смысл сравнивать элемент списка с длиной списка? `x == len(simples):` А это совсем бесполезно: `else:    pass`. Со списком простых нужно сначала задаться вопросом - он будет переиспользоваться много раз?

Comment: `for x in simples` ... `x == len(simples)` - Вы понимаете, что тут делаете?

Answer (score 1):

```
simples = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
a = 11
while True:
    b = 0
    a += 1
    for i in range(len(simples)):
        if a % simples[i] == 0:
            b += 1
    if b == 0:
        simples.append(a)
    if a == 10000:
        break
print(simples)
```

Comment: После `b += 1` тоже имеет смысл `break` поставить. И если у вас `while True` всё-равно ограничен конкретным диапазоном по `a`, то почему не заменить его на `for a in range(12, 10000)`?

Comment: а в чем преимущество for a in range?

Comment: 1) Тем, что это одна строка вместо пяти (`a = 11`, `while True:`, `a += 1`, `if a == 10000:`, `break`) 2) Тем, что глядя на эту короткую строку мы видим сразу все условия работы цикла, не нужно искать по коду что там ещё с `a` делается до и во время цикла. В коротком коде это может и не так важно, но из таких мелочей складывается хороший код.